# snapshot of collection? Firebase w/ js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**What I need to do:**
wanting to check the snapshot to see if anyone else has already taken that username. Seeing if the user input is already in use (the title of the document inside 'users')

I'm trying to get a snapshot of each document title, so a snapshot of the collection info. I know I could do something like mapping each value into an array but the username count is massive and I feel like that might affect performance?

Heres what I have:

```
const snap = firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.data())
        })
```

and this returns saying that snapshot.data() is not a function, if I remove .data() its a large mess of everything, I can post it if you would like.

Comment: It seems like you want to filter the documents in "users" to find the one that indicates the name is taken, instead of querying for the entire collection.  You might always want to consider reviewing the documentation for how to process the results of a query.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether a document with a specific name as its ID already exists, you can do:

```
const snap = firestore().collection('users').doc('Tobias').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.exists)
})
```

So this logs `true` is a document named `Tobias` exists, and false otherwise.